# How to iterate over HTTP response code in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, http

I am using import java.net.http.HttpClient
and my code is as follows:

```
try {
val response = httpClient.send(httpRequest, BodyHandlers.ofString())
...
when (response.statusCode()) {
                200 -> {
                    result = decodedResponse
                } else -> {
                    val errorResponse = Json.decodeFromString<ErrorObject>(response.body())
                    throw handleCustomError(errorResponse.error, errorResponse.error_description)
                }
            }
return result
} catch (ex: Exception) {
   
            throw Exception("Service is unavailable!")
        }
```

my handleCustomError iterates over the different types of status codes 401,403,404 etc and throws user friendly exception. But I dont think that code is ever reached. Instead I see the generic exception thrown by the catch block.

How can I make sure to iterate over the different status code?

Comment: If you throw an exception within a `try` block and are catching the generic `Exception`, the one you threw will be caught. Perhaps you don't actually need the `try..catch`

Comment: That suggestion worked! Thank you so much!